# Autosize column not working in ag-Grid with RxJS in case of Mobile View

Tags: reactjs

Autosize column is not working in ag-Grid with ReactJS in mobile view

1)I have tried using autoSizeAllColumns() but still i face the issue in mobile case
2)I have also tried by using api.sizeColumnsToFit() but couldn't resolve this issue